# libreadline - fgetc returns different values for the enter key

Tags: c, unix, readline, tty

`fgetc` returns a different value for the enter key after
calling libreadline's `rl_callback_handler_install()`. It changes from line feed (`\n`) to carriage return (`\r`).

How is this possible? I've read the [source](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=readline) but could not figure out what mechanism is used to achieve this.

Also, but less important, is this feature or a bug?

```c
// compile with gcc -o main.o main.c -lreadline

#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

static void foo_rl_callback(char *line)
{
    // do stuff
}

static void get_enter_key(void)
{
    printf("press enter!\n");
    printf("fgetc=%d\n", fgetc(stdin));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("readline: %s\n", rl_library_version);

    get_enter_key();
    rl_callback_handler_install(NULL, foo_rl_callback);
    get_enter_key();
    rl_callback_handler_remove();
    get_enter_key();

    return 0;
}
```

output (assuming user only presses the enter key):

```
readline: 8.1
press enter!

fgetc=10
press enter!
fgetc=13
press enter!

fgetc=10
```

Comment: Run your program with `strace`. `libreadline` changes terminal settings with `ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...})`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure but I believe this is being done by [`prepare_terminal_settings`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/rltty.c#n503) (there are several versions of that function; the link goes to the version that *should* be being used on any system shipped in the past 15 years or so).

This function uses [`tcsetattr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcsetattr.html) to twiddle a whole bunch of flags that control the behavior of a Unix terminal or pseudo-terminal.  In particular, it turns the ICANON bit *off*, which means, [among many other things](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_06), that U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN coming down the serial line is *not* converted to U+000A LINE FEED anymore.

While readline is active, you should be using *only* the readline API to interact with the terminal, not `fgetc(stdin)`.